# Как изменить положения ползунка через jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ion-rangeslider

Всем привет.
Сверстал калькулятор - http://tokmaganbet.ru/sites/moto. В нем ionRangeSlider, все ок, но как можно менять ползунок и его параметры в ЗАВИСИМОСТИ от выбора пунктов(radio) через jquery? 
Можно отключать ionRangeSlider у выбранного блока? Потом снова его подключить и т.д.

```
 $("#calc1").ionRangeSlider({
  min: 0,
  max: 300,
  step: 5,
  from_min: 30,
  hide_min_max: 1,
});

if ($('#calc_right2').is(':checked')) {
   $("#calc1").ionRangeSlider({
      min: 0,
      max: 300,
      step: 5,
      from_min: 50,
      hide_min_max: 1,
   });
}
```

Создавать 2 калькулятора и скрывать их по-очереди - не вариант, так как если это все считать, то проблемно... В документации насчет этого ничего не написано. 
P.S: Адаптив в конце сделаю)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не проще ли использовать `input range`? Вроде проще.

Comment: Нет, так проще, вот нашел ответ - http://jsbin.com/qicapibame/edit?js,output

Comment: Чем так проще, подключать либу которую пора выкинуть и забыть. не вижу простоты.